# How can you enable the iOS 6.0 panorama camera within an application?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm working on an app for iOS 6 that utilizes the camera, but I've been unable to figure out how to enable the options which would allow the user to take a panoramic shot.  I've got everything working as far as taking a normal photo goes, but would like to give the user the option to use the new panorama feature in iOS 6 in the app.

I've scoured the net and not been able to find any information (SO, Apple Dev Center, etc).  I'm unable to determine whether this is even a possibility or not. Can we use this, and if so, how?

Comment: I am facing the same issue as your, I would like to know if you have got any solution?

Comment: I've still not found any information.  When I do, I will be sure to update my post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible. Access to the camera is only possible via `UIImagePickerController` or through `AVFramework`, and neither of these provide this functionality.

`AVFramework` gives you the data stream from the camera, and you have to handle that yourself. Unless you want to implement your own panoramic feature, this isn't appropriate.

Whilst there are settings to adjust flash, video/image and rear/front in `UIImagePickerController`, there are none to enable the native panoramic feature.

In a similar vain to HDR photographs, Panoramic capture is only available within the Camera app.

Comment: Are there any libraries that enable this in AVFoundation yet?

Comment: No, the situation has not changed

Comment: I found a library [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062932/libraries-to-capture-panorama-in-ios-6), but not sure if its reliable.. Could you be so kind to help me with this?