# Capture panorama image from iPhone camera in ios6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6, panoramas

Is there any way to programatically create a panorama image using iPhone camera ? like in iOS 6 capture panorama image feature.

Any idea how it's work or API on it, which is help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: add some code so i can get idea :)

Comment: @Rocks i do not have any code and idea on it.so,if you have any idea on it please share with me...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666523/how-can-you-enable-the-ios-6-0-panorama-camera-within-an-application

Comment: Have you solved it? I have the same need, even for any 3rd party library.

Comment: @Idan no i don't get any proper solution on it...

Comment: Look [this][1] answer. There are sample with objctive-c provided.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062932/libraries-to-capture-panorama-in-ios-6

Comment: @skyline Is there any progress on this? I am also looking for this...

Comment: @iSeeker is there any progress on this ?

Comment: @DipenChudasama No, I have not gone forward with this idea..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. Apple has not made the APIs available to developers. Only the camera app has this feature. And yes, this is a duplicate.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above Apple doesn't have an API for this, but there are open source panorama projects, check out this question: [360° panorama libraries for ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763978/360-panorama-libraries-for-ios)

Comment: Thank You for your answer.but in the given link all answer is provide static images view or capture more than one image from iphone camera and provide 360 degree view.i need only one image like in iphone 5 or https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/360-panorama/id377342622?mt=8  app provide.you have any idea which way it's working please share.

Comment: Do you mean you want the end result to be a single image?

Comment: Yes.it's like in IOS 6 in iphone 5 Panorama capturing image feature.