# Device motion detection in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, accelerometer, panorama-control

I want to detect the device motion like `Panorama` i.e. `motion from my left side to Right side`.

I tried with the `accelerometer` but i can't able to do it.

I like to move one image in a straight line as the device move.

My code is as follow:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setUpdateInterval:1/60];
    [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer]setDelegate:self];
}
```

## pragma mark - Accelerometer Delegate

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:
(UIAcceleration *)acceleration{

    valueX = acceleration.x*100.0;
    valueY = acceleration.y*30.0;

    float newX = (float)(ball.center.x + valueX);

    CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(newX, 50);
    ball.center = newCenter;

}
```

How can I do this? Because there are many apps who uses this.

Please guide me.

Thanks..

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062932/libraries-to-capture-panorama-in-ios-6

Comment: Also try out these links https://github.com/SpotMetrix/Panoramic , http://krpano.com/docu/html5/