# How to detect iPhone's movement across while taking panorama images?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, gyroscope, uiaccelerometer

How can we detect across movement of an iPhone while taking panorama image?

[image]

NOTE: I am developing a custom panorama app and need to detect this movement to take panorama image.

Please let me know.

Comment: This may help you. [Device motion detection in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779324/device-motion-detection-in-ios). Also this may help you, [Apple gyroscope sample code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245733/apple-gyroscope-sample-code). Though this is just for vertical panoramic-kind movements. This may give you an idea on how to proceed. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Sir, did the above links help you?

Comment: Thanks Parth. Yes, it did help to some extent. We are still unable to detect the rotation movement yet.