# iOS - How to create panorama within iOS application? A sphere panorama. How to automatically capture images using gyroscope position?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, gyroscope, panoramas

I am making an app that is supposed to create 360 panorama images (not only linear but also up and down so in effect a sphere panorama). I've been googling around trying to find some related thing and so far the only thing close to it is this

[libraries to CAPTURE panorama in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062932/libraries-to-capture-panorama-in-ios-6)

I have tested the library in the sample
https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVStitch
but it is unable to do any reasonable work for indoor images.

The app I am making is supposed to work indoor as well as out door. Also, I am still not sure how to automatically capture images based on gyroscope position.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any success in capturing sphere panorama ?

Comment: Sorry @RahulPatel I had to give up on the project because it was taking too much time.

Answer (score 0):

I daresay what you are attempting to do is really hard, and original work, not something you're going to find ready-made.

The link you posted uses OpenCV to stitch together the image stream into a composite image. You'd need to combine that with code that recognizes rotational data from the gyroscope, and map the image data you get onto the interior of a sphere. The best way to do that is probably using OpenGL and textures. You'd map your images into a set of textures and then map those textures onto the surface of a sphere. If there is no rotation, you could map the textures onto a plane and use the same code for flat panoramas.

OpenCV and OpenGL are both advanced APIs, and not conducive to cut-and-paste programming. You will need to roll up your sleeves and do a lot of learning in order to use them if you haven't before.

Comment: My knowledge is limited to objective-c and I virtually have no experience with OpenGL or OpenCV. I guess you're right, I am going to have to learn these and blending algorithms to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the Hugin Open Source Panoramic Stitching software for a better understanding of how stitching works. http://hugin.sourceforge.net/