# Cant capture 360 pano from iOS built-in camera

Tags: ios

I have a big problem! I need to capture 360 panoramic image in my iOS app.But apple's iPhone built-in camera lets to capture panoramic image, which can have maximum 270 degrees....

I do many resarches, but can't understand how I can continue.....

Can anyone help me? What can I do for capturing 360 pano image in iOS app.

Comment: Hello Hayk, welcome on Stack overflow!
Have you checked if other users tried to figure out a solution for the same problem? I can see that something similar has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377582/creating-a-360-photo-experience-on-ios-mobile-device), also in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20867819/ios-how-to-create-panorama-within-ios-application-a-sphere-panorama-how-to-a). If that doesn't help you may check [this article](https://hypersense-software.com/360-degrees-image-capture-on-ios).
The point is to search here if the question has been alre

Comment: Hello dear funder7! Thanks for your response! Of course I have already checked and read those articles , but they didnt help me...

Comment: Hello, I suggest you to read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it contains plenty of useful information that will help you to find somebody to help you :-) Good luck

Comment: Oh, thank you for your compassion :)))