# Using OpenCV in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, opencv, image-processing

After adding the OpenCV 2 framework in my xcode project, I tried searching for samlpes or tutorials for integration with swift.

Are there any good tutorials for the same?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

OpenCV is a framework written in C++. Apple's [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html) tell us that

> You cannot import C++ code directly into Swift. Instead, create an Objective-C or C wrapper for C++ code.

so you cannot directly import and use OpenCV in a swift project, but this is actually not bad at all because you (need) continue to use the C++ syntax of the framework which is pretty well documented all over the net.

So how do you proceed?

1. Create a new Objective-C++ class (.h, **.mm**) for calling C++ OpenCV

*OpenCVWrapper.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface OpenCVWrapper : NSObject

    + (UIImage *)processImageWithOpenCV:(UIImage*)inputImage;

@end
```

*OpenCVWrapper.mm* (use the File -> New... Wizard for Objective-C and rename the .m file to .mm)

```
#include "OpenCVWrapper.h"
#import "UIImage+OpenCV.h" // See below to create this

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

@implementation OpenCVWrapper : NSObject

    + (UIImage *)processImageWithOpenCV:(UIImage*)inputImage {
        Mat mat = [inputImage CVMat];
        
        // do your processing here
        ...
        
        return [UIImage imageWithCVMat:mat];
    }

@end
```

As an alternative to creating new classes such as the example OpenCVWrapper.h/mm you can use Objective-C categories to extend existing Objective-C classes with OpenCV functionality. For instance UIImage+OpenCV category:

*UIImage+OpenCV.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

@interface UIImage (OpenCV)

    //cv::Mat to UIImage
+ (UIImage *)imageWithCVMat:(const cv::Mat&)cvMat;
- (id)initWithCVMat:(const cv::Mat&)cvMat;

    //UIImage to cv::Mat
- (cv::Mat)CVMat;
- (cv::Mat)CVMat3;  // no alpha channel
- (cv::Mat)CVGrayscaleMat;

@end
```

*UIImage+OpenCV.mm*

See https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVSwiftStitch/blob/master/SwiftStitch/UIImage%2BOpenCV.mm

2. Update the [Bridging-Header](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) to make all Objective-C++ classes you created available to Swift by importing our newly created wrappers (`#import "OpenCVWrapper.h"`)
3. Use your wrapper in your Swift files:

   ```swift
   let image = UIImage(named: "image.jpeg")
   let processedImage = OpenCVWrapper.processImageWithOpenCV(image)
   ```

All Objective-C++ classes included in the bridge header are available directly from Swift.

Comment: Hello I am new to OpenCV. Can you please tell me what should be there in UIImage+OpenCV category?? Should I download it from somewhere?

Comment: @GMHSJ: It is extension of UIImage which help to convert to and from  cv::Mat structure  to UIImage.So you have to create it in your project.

Comment: #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp> Should be included before everything else. If not some conflicts will appear.

Comment: @TomasCamin, I have asked a question somewhat similar to this one regarding an error when building OpenCV for iOS. I would really appreciate it if you could take a look at the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534183/opencv-error-assertions-failed-on-ios.

Comment: @TomasCamin, how about the opencv swift framework that is available for download at Opencv.org site? Does it have all the wrapper classes or do we still need to use it in conjunction with the opencv pod?

Comment: Hello, i'm new at OpenCV & C-Obj. can you tell me what i should put in `+ (UIImage *)processImageWithOpenCV:(UIImage*)inputImage {}` for face classification? Thank you.

Comment: hi @Tomas, the Bridging-Header link has broken, could you please update it? I'd like to learn this as well. thanks

Answer (score 38):

I have a demo on github:

https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVSwiftStitch

It shows how to use the OpenCV stitcher from a Swift-based project. There is not a lot to the openCV side, it's really just a demo of how to put the various pieces together.

As Swift won't talk C++ directly, it uses a thin Objective-C++ wrapper to mediate between the iOS side and the openCV side.

Made in answer to these  questions:
[Can I mix Swift with C++? Like the Objective - C .mm files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042774/can-i-mix-swift-with-c-like-the-objective-c-mm-files/24045562#24045562)
[libraries to CAPTURE panorama in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062932/libraries-to-capture-panorama-in-ios-6/14064788#14064788)

Comment: @Kashif, I have replied via the contact details on your website.

Comment: This demo (OpenCVSwiftStitch) on github is the best tutorial and practical demo I have found so far on integrating Swift with OpenCV. It answers questions, gives install instructions and shows what to put into the UIImage+OpenCV category implementation. 
After reading this I could finally get going, convert an image from UIImage format to OpenCV Mat, do some processing, convert back and display the image

Comment: @Paulus - thanks for the feedback. I'm glad you found it useful.

Comment: @foundry - I was attempting to play around with your code and converted it to Swift 3.0. The code compiles but I'm getting an error, "Can't stitch images, error code = 1
CGImageCreate: invalid image size: 0 x 0." Just wondered if you had come across this error before and do have any thoughts on a potential resolution?

Comment: @Tom - thanks for the heads-up. I was waiting for someone to attempt a Swift 3.0 conversion! I'll investigate. Meanwhile you should add breakpoints to verify that you have input images with non-zero dimensions, and you can also check the cv::Mat images size() property to narrow down the cause.

Comment: @Tom - see the latest updates to the repo. Swift 3.0 was breaking due to stricter type coercion requirements - fixed.

Comment: @foundry, I saw your demo and I was able to build and run, but I noticed the OpenCV.org has a swift framework for download now. Does it replace the need to use the OpenCV pod and to create the OBJC wrappers that call the C++ classes and expose them to Swift?