# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on swift 2 and objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, swift2

I am trying to figure out issue with my code. I am trying to process image using OpenCV in my iOS application. i have written method and did bridge-header as its [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30909377/659944).

Here is my .h file:

```
#ifndef OpenCVWrapper_h
#define OpenCVWrapper_h

#endif

#import<UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import<Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface OpenCVWrapper: NSObject
+(NSSTring*) processImageWithOpenCV:(UIImage*)inputImage;
@end
```

my .mm file is

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include "OpenCVWrapper.h"
#import "UIImage+OpenCV.h"
#import "UIKit/UIKit.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

@implementation OpenCVWrapper : NSObject
+(NSString*) processImageWithOpenCV:(UIImage*)inputImage{
    Mat mat = [inputImage CVMat];
    /////////////Image processing etc

    char *cstr = new char[Reading.length() + 1];
    strcpy(cstr, Reading.c_str());
    reverse(cstr, cstr + strlen(cstr));
    const char* str = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(cstr);
    NSString* string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:str];

    return string;
}      /////// I get error here
@end
    return "Success"
```

Here is how i am calling this method:

```
let reading = OpenCVWrapper.processImageWithOpenCV(Image)
```

I get error as mentioned in above code. First error is

```
`thread 1 signal sigabrt`
```

and when i try to continue. i get:

```
`Thread1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`
```

I am stuck here for 2 days and unable to find right direction. There is no stack trace. just output of what i am printing in log.

Please point me to right direction.

Regards.

Comment: A couple of thoughts - the `Image` you pass in, is it a class or an instance of an images (asking because its capitalized)? Also, have you tried setting a breakpoint for "All Exceptions" and seeing where that ends up?

Comment: plz show us where str comes from - I have the suspicion that it doesn't belong to you and the app crashes when that is deallocated. You could just remove the NSString call as a test. just return @""

Comment: its an instance of UIImage

Comment: well i am updating my code. on returning @"". i get same issue

Comment: @Daij-Djan i have updated the code. please check. it is printing the str value. but same issue at `{`

Comment: loose the cast. and don't use str but cstr

Comment: I'd try to identify exactly which line is crashing using log statements. Maybe use `strrev` instead of `reverse` - if it's doing a literal reverse maybe it's putting the null termination on the front, thus messing up the string

Comment: @Daij-Djan i removed the str, and used cstr. no NSString conversion. but still same issue

Comment: @RichTolley i also removed reverse and instead i wrote a loop to reverse the char series. but issue is same.... I am wondering why it isn't shwing any log in output window. :(