# Video processing with OpenCV in IOS Swift project

Tags: c++, ios, swift, opencv, video-processing

I've integrated opencv in Swift IOS project using bridging header (to connect Swift to Objective C) and a Objective C wrapper (to connect Objective C to C++). Using this method I can pass single images from the Swift code, analyse them in the C++ files and get them back.

[I've seen that opencv provides CvVideoCamera object that can be integrated with an Objective C UIViewController.](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/ios/video_processing/video_processing.html)

But since my UIViewController are written in Swift I've wondered if this is possible as well?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is an update to my initial answer after I had a chance to play with this myself.  Yes, it is possible to use `CvVideoCamera` with a view controller written in Swift. If you just want to use it to display video from the camera in your app, it's really easy.

`#import <opencv2/highgui/cap_ios.h>` via the bridging header.  Then, in your view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CvVideoCameraDelegate {
...
    var myCamera : CvVideoCamera!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        ...
        myCamera = CvVideoCamera(parentView: imageView)
        myCamera.delegate = self
        ...
    }
}
```

The `ViewController` cannot actually conform to the `CvVideoCameraDelegate` protocol, but `CvVideoCamera` won't work without a delegate, so we work around this problem by declaring `ViewController` to adopt the protocol without implementing any of its methods.  This will trigger a compiler warning, but the video stream from the camera will be displayed in the image view.

Of course, you might want to implement the `CvVideoCameraDelegate`'s (only) `processImage()` method to process video frames before displaying them.  The reason you cannot implement it in Swift is because it uses a C++ type, `Mat`.

So, you will need to write an Objective-C++ class whose instance can be set as camera's delegate. The `processImage()` method in that Objective-C++ class will be called by `CvVideoCamera` and will in turn call code in your Swift class.  Here are some sample code snippets.
In `OpenCVWrapper.h`:

```
// Need this ifdef, so the C++ header won't confuse Swift
#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif

// This is a forward declaration; we cannot include *-Swift.h in a header.
@class ViewController;

@interface CvVideoCameraWrapper : NSObject
...
-(id)initWithController:(ViewController*)c andImageView:(UIImageView*)iv;
...
@end
```

In the wrapper implementation, `OpenCVWrapper.mm` (it's an Objective-C++ class, hence the .mm extension):

```
#import <opencv2/highgui/cap_ios.h>
using namespace cv;
// Class extension to adopt the delegate protocol
@interface CvVideoCameraWrapper () <CvVideoCameraDelegate>
{
}
@end
@implementation CvVideoCameraWrapper
{
    ViewController * viewController;
    UIImageView * imageView;
    CvVideoCamera * videoCamera;
}

-(id)initWithController:(ViewController*)c andImageView:(UIImageView*)iv
{
    viewController = c;
    imageView = iv;

    videoCamera = [[CvVideoCamera alloc] initWithParentView:imageView];
    // ... set up the camera
    ...
    videoCamera.delegate = self;

    return self;
}
// This #ifdef ... #endif is not needed except in special situations
#ifdef __cplusplus
- (void)processImage:(Mat&)image
{
    // Do some OpenCV stuff with the image
    ...
}
#endif
...
@end
```

Then you put `#import "OpenCVWrapper.h"` in the bridging header, and the Swift view controller might look like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
...
    var videoCameraWrapper : CvVideoCameraWrapper!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        ...
        self.videoCameraWrapper = CvVideoCameraWrapper(controller:self, andImageView:imageView)
        ...
    }
```

See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html about forward declarations and Swift/C++/Objective-C interop.  There is plenty of info on the web about `#ifdef __cplusplus` and `extern "C"` (if you need it).

In the `processImage()` delegate method you will likely need to interact with some OpenCV API, for which you will also have to write wrappers.  You can find some info on that elsewhere, for example here: [Using OpenCV in Swift iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30908593/using-opencv-in-swift-ios)

**Update 09/03/2019**

At the community request, see comments, the sample code has been placed on GitHub at https://github.com/aperedera/opencv-swift-examples.

Also, the current, as of this writing, version of the OpenCV iOS framework no longer allows Swift code to use the header (now it's in videoio/cap_ios.h) that declares the `CvVideoCameraDelegate` protocol, so you cannot just include it in the bridging header and declare the view controller to conform to the protocol to simply display camera video in your app.

Comment: Can you please share your full code of video processing with opencv ?

Comment: @parth, what's you suggestion about the best way of sharing the code with opencv?

Comment: Sharing your demo code via GitHub is best way I think. It will help all devs who are stuck at some points.

Comment: Will try and find some spare time to do that, looks like there is a lot of interest in this.  Thank you for the encouragement, @parth.

Comment: Done, the code is on GitHub now, see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, It will help us.