# OpenCV IOS Swift 2 :How to implement the CvVideoCameraDelegate protocol process Video Frames

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, swift2

Okay so I've been using OpenCV and want to use it for IOS with Swift 2.0... I successfully implemented it and I tested it with a few functions/examples, it worked fine! But The application in thought I have is a Live Camera object detection. So using a cascade classifier I will do this, but the thing I have trouble with is setting up the CvVideoCameraDelegate protocol with my ViewController; I'm trying to use this [tutrial/example](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/ios/video_processing/video_processing.html) to set it up....
But I'm having trouble trying to set it up in swift.... Can someone please advise the correct way to set it up?

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial you are referencing is about how to do this in Objective-C.  Doing it in Swift is a little trickier.  You will need to set up an Objective-C class as the camera's delegate, and your Swift code will have to communicate with the `CvVideoCamera` object via this Objective-C class and possibly other helper Objective-C classes.  Please see this question/answer: [Video processing with OpenCV in IOS Swift project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413951/video-processing-with-opencv-in-ios-swift-project/37427098#37427098)