# camera view does not appear in a swift/objective-c++ (opencv) project - ios 10.3 xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, opencv, objective-c++

I would like to link OpenCV with swift/objective c++ to be able to develop applications for ios. I found that CocoaPods work reasonably well with OpenCV pods. So I used them as a starting point and tried some image stitching examples successfully. However, when I try to capture images from the camera, I cannot see the output at the display. The code run and loops around the `captureOutput` function but the camera image is not displayed. It seems that the code runs in the background:

**Objective c++ code:**

```
@interface VideoSource () <AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>
  @property (strong, nonatomic) AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer;
  @property (strong, nonatomic) AVCaptureSession *captureSession;
@end

@implementation VideoSource

- (void)setTargetView:(UIView *)targetView {
   if (self.previewLayer == nil) {
       return;
   }
   self.previewLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspectFill;
   self.previewLayer.frame = targetView.bounds;
   self.previewLayer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2);
   [targetView.layer addSublayer:self.previewLayer];
   std::cout<<"VideoSource setTargetView ... done "<<std::endl;
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
       _captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
       _captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480;

       AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
       NSError *error = nil;
       AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:device error:&error];
       [_captureSession addInput:input];

       AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
       output.videoSettings = @{(NSString *)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)};
       output.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES;
       [_captureSession addOutput:output];

       dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("VideoQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
       [output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];

       _previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layer];

       std::cout<<"VideoSource init ... done "<<std::endl;

    }

    return self;
}


- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

  uint8_t *base;
  int width, height, bytesPerRow;
  base = (uint8_t*)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
  width = (int)CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
  height = (int)CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
  bytesPerRow = (int)CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);

  Mat mat = Mat(height, width, CV_8UC4, base);

  //Processing here
  [self.delegate processFrame:mat];

  CGImageRef imageRef = [self CGImageFromCVMat:mat];
  dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     self.previewLayer.contents = (__bridge id)imageRef;
  });

  CGImageRelease(imageRef);
  CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress( imageBuffer, 0 );

  std::cout<<"VideoSource captureOutput ... done "<<std::endl;
}

- (void)start {
   [self.captureSession startRunning];
   std::cout<<"VideoSource start ... done "<<std::endl;
}




- (CGImageRef)CGImageFromCVMat:(Mat)cvMat {
   if (cvMat.elemSize() == 4) {
   cv::cvtColor(cvMat, cvMat, COLOR_BGRA2RGBA);
}
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cvMat.data length:cvMat.elemSize()*cvMat.total()];
  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;

  if (cvMat.elemSize() == 1) {
      colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
  } else {
      colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
  }

  CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);

  // Creating CGImage from cv::Mat
  CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(cvMat.cols,                                 
  //width
                                    cvMat.rows,                                 
  //height
                                    8,                                          
  //bits per component
                                    8 * cvMat.elemSize(),                       
  //bits per pixel
                                    cvMat.step[0],                            
  //bytesPerRow
                                    colorSpace,                                 
  //colorspace

  kCGImageAlphaNone|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,// bitmap info
                                    provider,                                   
  //CGDataProviderRef
                                    NULL,                                       
  //decode
                                    false,                                      
  //should interpolate
                                    kCGRenderingIntentDefault                   
 //intent
                                    );

  CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
  CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
  //std::cout<<"VideoSource CGImageFromCVMat ... done "<<std::endl;

  return imageRef;
}

@end
```

**The swift side:**

```
    @IBOutlet var spinner:UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet weak var previewView: UIView!
let wrapper = Wrapper()
```

and then in the call function:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(animated)
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
self.wrapper.setTargetView(self.previewView)
self.wrapper.start()
}
```

Comment: Just to point out that the code above is mostly from source code I found here: https://github.com/akira108/MinimumOpenCVLiveCamera
This example is based on previous version of ios/xcode, which I guess it is one of the reason that it isn't directly compatible with the version of ios 10.2 /xcode 8.

Comment: Since I manage to build and install it under ios 10.2/xcode 8, I'm not sure of what needs to change/add.

Comment: This is an example of image stitching with openCV/Swift/Objective-C++ that works well under ios 10.2/xcode8 and cocoapods (porting OpenCV 3.2): https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVSwiftStitch

Comment: I have tried the above source code both with OpenCV 3.2 and OpenCV 2.4.12.3. Both ported via cocoapods. Outcome is the same but I cannot see the camera view in the app display window.
Also I found that it is easier to handle OpenCV 2.4.12.3. I can now include a  CvVideoCameraDelegate in the swift viewcontroller similar to what this post suggests: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413951/video-processing-with-opencv-in-ios-swift-project/37427098#37427098 
However, even by following the CvVideoCameraDelegate I cannot see the camera output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this problem. The solution was simply to connect the UI (main.storyboard) to the ViewController.swift by dragging the specific UI components.

Both paradigms work:

1. Source code posted above adapted from: https://github.com/akira108/MinimumOpenCVLiveCamera 
   This require to connect the `UIView` of the `main.storyboard` to the `previewView` (UIView) in the `ViewController.swift`  (just drag and drop to create the connection)
2. Involving the `CvVideoCameraDelegate` class in the swift Viewcontroller ([Video processing with OpenCV in IOS Swift project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413951/video-processing-with-opencv-in-ios-swift-project/37427098#37427098)). Here, I inserted a `UIImage` object at the `main.storyboard` and connected this object to `previewImage` at the `ViewController`. Because this example requires to use specific opencv header within swift (`cap_ios.h`), I only tested with with OpenCV 2.4.