# objective C opencv wrapper for swift project does not see STL headers

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, opencv

I was following another thread, as per answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30909377/6293090

The STL header can't be found by compiler when they are imported or included from objective C files
The line:

```
\#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

or:

```
\#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

In my opencv.m wrapper  compiler can't find headers included by opencv.hpp or , ('list' file not found),
However, If I add C++ file to the project and use the same #include line in it, it compiles fine. I haven't found separate header search path for objective C in the project's build setting.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an Objective-C++ file, one with `.mm` extension instead of `.m`, and then you can mix Objective-C and C++ code in that implementation file as well as include C++ headers into it.

Create an Objective-C (`.m`) file in Xcode and rename it to have the `.mm` extension, and you're all set!

Here is another related question that might be helpful: [Video processing with OpenCV in IOS Swift project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413951/video-processing-with-opencv-in-ios-swift-project/37427098#37427098).