# Different C++ include statements throws errors in the Objective-C header

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, opencv, objective-c++

I'm trying to use OpenCV in Objective-C++ code which I will call from Swift. First I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24005242/2656632) for connecting Objective-C and Swift. So after these manipulations I get three files:

Bridging-Header.h:

```
#import "opencvtest.h"
```

opencvtest.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
//#include <dlib/image_loader/load_image.h>

@interface CustomObject : NSObject

- (cv::Mat)cvMatFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image;


@end
```

opencvtest.mm:

```
#import "opencvtest.h"
```

Error:

```
/Users/user/Documents/XcodeProjects/Swift_HelloWorld/Swift_HelloWorld/Swift_HelloWorld-Bridging-Header.h:5:9: note: in file included from /Users/user/Documents/XcodeProjects/Swift_HelloWorld/Swift_HelloWorld/Swift_HelloWorld-Bridging-Header.h:5:
#import "opencvtest.h"
        ^ /Users/user/Documents/XcodeProjects/Swift_HelloWorld/Swift_HelloWorld/opencvtest.h:23:4: error: expected a type
- (cv::Mat)cvMatFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image;    ^ <unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/user/Documents/XcodeProjects/Swift_HelloWorld/Swift_HelloWorld/Swift_HelloWorld-Bridging-Header.h'
```

Also, if I add line `#include <dlib/image_loader/load_image.h>` in the opencvtest.h then I get:

```
/usr/local/include/DLIB/string/string.h:7:10: error: 'sstream' file not found
#include <sstream>
         ^
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/user/Documents/XcodeProjects/Swift_HelloWorld/Swift_HelloWorld/Swift_HelloWorld-Bridging-Header.h'
```

I want to note that all these errors occurs only when I put these include statements in this header, **when I used it in .mm file all works fine**. But I need them in the header for declarations.

So, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface of your Objective-C objects usable in Swift and thus visible in the bridging header cannot reference any C++ types.  You need to write an Objective-C++ wrapper in such a way that C++ types are only mentioned in your `.mm` files and in headers used in the `.mm` files.  You can hide the parts of the interface that use C++ by using extensions in Objective-C++ code.  Please see the following question and questions referenced there for examples of how to do that:

[objective C opencv wrapper for swift project does not see STL headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668641/objective-c-opencv-wrapper-for-swift-project-does-not-see-stl-headers/37669269#37669269)

Comment: Hm... I didn't think about that. Absolutely clear, thanks! :)