# Capture the panorama image from iPhone camera in ios7 & later

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, camera, panorama-control

I am working one real estate application, User needs to capture his area through the panorama camera from the application. Can any body suggest how can we capture the panoramic image from iPhone programmatically . If we can achieve it then please provide the links or tutorials if not also please provide some links provided by apple. Kindly waiting for your answers & suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no way to take a panorama from an app, only from the Apple camera app.

This question has been asked and answered several times on Stack Overflow, please see the questions under "Related" at the right, and these and their related questions:

- [Capture panorama image from iPhone camera in ios6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604808/capture-panorama-image-from-iphone-camera-in-ios6)
- [libraries to CAPTURE panorama in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062932/libraries-to-capture-panorama-in-ios-6)
- [How can you enable the iOS 6.0 panorama camera within an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666523/how-can-you-enable-the-ios-6-0-panorama-camera-within-an-application)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was searched every thing. I didn't found the apple documented answer.I am searching for it.If you have please provide the links.